# Add translatable text in template file

Tags: i18n-l10n

I am going to add a custom string by [**t**](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/t/6)() function in node.tpl.php. However, where should I add the translated string for the original string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go to admin/build/translate and translate your defined words, it's search is case sensitive

Comment: Is this for D6 or D7? I can't find the translate interface in D7...I have the i18n module installed

Comment: Its Drupal 6, for Drupal 7 use `admin/config/regional/translate`

Comment: I realized that the search interface is case-sensitive...my bad :s